# Object detection samples in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Does anyone know where can I find object detection sample code in OpenCV?

I want to track an object with a specified clolor.

Thanks

Comment: I updated the broken link in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

There are bunch of examples in OpenCV distribution (samples folder).

There you can find `camshiftdemo.c` — exactly what you searching for.